# QWebInspector: How to switch tab manually

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtwebkit

When I use QWebInspector (python, PyQT4), it always opens with default activated "Elements" tab.
Is there a way programmatically switch tab to Network?
Now it looks as:
[image: QWebInspector opens "Elements" tab]

What I want to see:
[image]

Script source:

```
import sys, PyQt4.QtCore, PyQt4.QtGui, PyQt4.QtWebKit

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = PyQt4.QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    webview = PyQt4.QtWebKit.QWebView()
    inspector = PyQt4.QtWebKit.QWebInspector()

    webview.page().settings().setAttribute(
        PyQt4.QtWebKit.QWebSettings.DeveloperExtrasEnabled, True
    )
    inspector.setPage(webview.page())

    inspector.showMaximized()

    webview.load(PyQt4.QtCore.QUrl('http://yahoo.com'))
    app.exec_()
```

Surely, appropriate С++/QT method is also suitable!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebInspector is based on web. You will need to get first and only child of inspector, it will be QWebView.

Like that:

```
QList<QWidget*> list = inspector.findChildren<QWidget *>();
QWebView* wv =(QWebView*) list.at(0);
```

Then connect to **javaScriptWindowObjectCleared** signal of this view, and in the connected slot execute javascript. You will need object to handle this. I called it **someObject**, for example

```
QObject::connect(
    wv->page()->mainFrame(), 
    SIGNAL(javaScriptWindowObjectCleared()),
    someObject, 
    SLOT(openNetworkTab())
);
```

add slot to **someObject**'s class:

```
void openNetworkTab(){
    wv->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript("document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){setTimeout(function(){document.querySelector('.toolbar-item.network').click()},200);});");
}
```

Delay 200 just to wait for all event bindings initialization before make click

Here list of all inspector tab classes, just in case: *.elements, .resources, .network, .scripts, .timeline, .profiles, .audits, .console*

Comment: Hello, for qt 5.8 I get 
TypeError:​ null is not an object (evaluating 'document.querySelector('.toolbar-item.console')​.click')​ (at null:​1:​126)​. I delay for 3 seconds and all the tabs are visible when this exception happens